# Problem with running old Lyx files after upgrading Lyx

Tags: lyx

I used an earlier version of Lyx (2.0) to create my files.

After uploading to the latest version, when I run the old files today I get:

"The external program
pplatex
finished with an error. It is recommened you fix the cause of the external program's error (check the logs)."

This happens with all the files created with the earlier version of Lyx. Isn't Lyx backward compatible?

When I visit DOCUMENTS > LATEX LOG, it is showing blank (greyed out). Please help!

Comment: Welcome! Yes, LyX should be able to open and compile any older .lyx file. Unfortunately, we can't help you figure out the problem if you don't post a minimal example file https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: I understand that posting an MWE is difficult, but we need much more information. Which OS? Which tex-system? If windows, is pplatex newer than year 2010? Can you export the Lyx-file to a *.tex-file and does this *.tex-file compile? Or maybe export your *.lyx-files to *.tex and reimport them into lyx.

Comment: Your large posting of the lyx file shows version 2.2 and is truncated early in the dialog so this sample is not showing a problem other than it was been modified and partially pasted to a web site ! Do you have only one master file is it tex or lyx ? Make a backup copy set it read only Make a work copy Open the work copy with any other editor What are the first few lines ? For lyx 2.0 they should start #Lyx 2.0 Do you have an earlier smaller test file that behaves the same way ?

Comment: Please press the edit button in your question to add more context. Two of your answers are already deleted by the review process, and two more will be deleted soon I'm sure.

Comment: I have corrected answer to earlier 1.6 so it is earlier than the 2.0.1 stated since it needs to be older than your target version

Answer (score 2):

Once a 2.0 file has been adjusted to 2.2 (or 2.3) there will be objects that will not work if you try to reopen directly the .lyx in an older version. Unfortunately due to web limitations your sample was truncated and I had to adjust the file manually to get it to load in 2.3 without problems other than it wanted to load as Swedish!

[image]

It is normal for an applications new version to read an old version file and make adjustments to new format. However "back-porting" is notoriously difficult. In such case the "new" version would best be exported to a different type and then imported to "old" version.

Catch22 you do not have a working new application to back-port, so either

A) need a different build / continue to try to UpRev application

B) Handover file to  someone who can back-port/convert to version 2.0 or export in a suitable format for 2.0 however I could not guarantee it would be 100% successful in formatting.

My tests with your initial MWE which was tagged as 2.2 converts reasonably well in 2.0.1 but I do not know if parts are missing try this and compare

```
#LyX 2.0.1 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 345
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass memoir
\begin_preamble
\usepackage{lettrine}
%\usepackage{watermark}
%\usepackage{draftcopy}
\usepackage{showidx}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}
\date{}

%\newcounter{pl}
%\newcommand\ragmarpar[1]{%
%\stepcounter{pl}\label{pl-\thepl}%
%\ifthenelse{\isodd{\pageref{pl-\thepl}}}%
%{\marginpar{\raggedright #1}}
%{\marginpar{\raggedleft #1}}
%} 
%\makeindex

\setlength{\footnotesep}{12pt}
%\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=endash]{caption}
%\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{9.7pt}{12pt}\selectfont}

\usepackage[hang,splitrule]{footmisc}
\addtolength{\footskip}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{0.46cm}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{0.2cm}



%%%% Index Macro %%%%%%%%
%\renewenvironment{theindex}
%{\cleardoublepage\if@twocolumn
\@restonecolfalse
%\else
\@restonecoltrue
%\fi
%\columnseprule
%\z@
%\columnsep
%35\p@
%\twocolumn[\@makeschapterhead{\indexname}]%%
%%%\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
%%%{\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
%\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
%{\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
%\markboth{Index}{Index}
%\thispagestyle{folio}\parindent\z@
%\pagestyle{headings}
%\parskip\z@ \@plus .3\p@\relax
%\let\item\@idxitem}
%{\if@restonecol\onecolumn\else\clearpage\fi}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newbox\tempbox
\newdimen\nomenwidth
\newenvironment{symbollist}[1]{%
\addvspace{12pt}
\setbox\tempbox\hbox{#1\hskip1em}%
\global\nomenwidth\wd\tempbox
%\section*{Sumbol Description}
\noindent{\SectionHeadFont Symbol Description}\vskip6pt
\begin{multicols}{2}}{%
\end{multicols}\par\addvspace{12pt}}
\def\symbolentry#1#2{\par\noindent\@hangfrom{\hbox to
\nomenwidth{#1\hss}}#2\par}




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
%\makeindex{}


\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{type1cm}
%\makeatletter
%  \AddToShipoutPicture{%
%    \setlength{\@tempdimb}{.5\paperwidth}%
%    \setlength{\@tempdimc}{.5\paperheight}%
%    \setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}%
%    \put(\strip@pt\@tempdimb,\strip@pt\@tempdimc){%
%      \makebox(0,0){\rotatebox{45}{\textcolor[gray]{0.75}{\fontsize{5cm}{5cm}\selectfont{Draft}}}}
%   }
%}
%\makeatother 
%\makeindex 
%    \newenvironment{myindentpar}[1]%
  %   {\begin{list}{}%
 %            {\setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}}%
   %          \item[]%
   %  }
  %   {\end{list}}




\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{type1cm}

\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}% Tighter

\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{9.8pt}{16pt}\selectfont} 

\newenvironment{myindentpar}[1]%
 {\begin{list}{}%
         {\setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}}%
         \item[]%
 }
 {\end{list}}
\frenchspacing
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{11pt}{17pt}\selectfont} 
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.05}

%\usepackage{caption}
%\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,format=plain,indention=0cm,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
\end_preamble
\options openany
\use_default_options false
\begin_modules
theorems-ams
\end_modules
\language english
\inputencoding iso8859-3
\font_roman "utopia" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_default_family rmdefault
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100
\graphics default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize custom
\use_geometry true
\use_amsmath 1
\use_esint 1
\cite_engine basic
\use_bibtopic false
\paperorientation portrait
\paperwidth 140mm
\paperheight 210mm
\leftmargin 2.2cm
\topmargin 3cm
\rightmargin 2.2cm
\bottommargin 2.2cm
\secnumdepth -1
\tocdepth 5
\paragraph_separation indent
\quotes_language swedish
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 2
\paperpagestyle ruled
\bullet 0 1 29 -1
\bullet 1 0 24 -1
\bullet 2 2 21 -1
\bullet 3 0 6 -1
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Title
\paragraph_spacing single
\noindent
PLAYING IT BY EAR
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\noindent
\align center

\size largest
Cheryl Rao
\size default

\begin_inset VSpace smallskip
\end_inset


\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
thispagestyle{empty}
\end_layout

\end_inset


\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset


\shape slanted
\size footnotesize
\color black

\begin_inset VSpace vfill
\end_inset


\begin_inset VSpace vfill
\end_inset


\begin_inset VSpace vfill
\end_inset


\shape default
\size default
\color inherit

\begin_inset Graphics
    filename C:/home/oldhome/fn/GOA1556/goa1556finallogo.jpg
    height 1.2cm

\end_inset


\begin_inset space ~
\end_inset


\begin_inset space ~
\end_inset


\begin_inset space ~
\end_inset


\begin_inset Graphics
    filename C:/home/oldhome/fn/GOA1556/goldenheartlogo6.jpg
    lyxscale 10
    height 1.2cm

\end_inset


\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset

2018
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
thispagestyle{empty}
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\paragraph_spacing single
\noindent
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
setcounter{page}{1}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
sloppy
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\paragraph_spacing single
\noindent
\begin_inset Newpage pagebreak
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\noindent
\align center

\size footnotesize
\emph on
Playing It By Ear
\shape italic
\emph default

\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset

(c) 
\shape default
\emph on
2018 Cheryl Rao
\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset


\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset


\emph default

\begin_inset VSpace vfill
\end_inset


\begin_inset VSpace vfill
\end_inset


\begin_inset VSpace vfill
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\align center

\size footnotesize
\emph on
Published in 2018 by
\shape slanted
\emph default

\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\align center
\begin_inset Graphics
    filename C:/home/oldhome/fn/GOA1556/goa1556finallogo.jpg
    height 1.1cm

\end_inset


\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\align center

\size footnotesize
\emph on
Goa,1556, Sonarbhat, Saligao 403511 Goa, India.
 http://goa1556.goa-india.org, goa1556@gmail.com +91-832-2409490
\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset

in association with
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\align center
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
thispagestyle{empty}
\end_layout

\end_inset


\begin_inset Graphics
    filename C:/home/oldhome/fn/GOA1556/goldenheartlogo6.jpg
    lyxscale 10
    height 1.1cm

\end_inset


\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset


\size footnotesize
\emph on
The Margao (Rua Abade Faria) bookshop with a difference
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\align center

\size footnotesize
\emph on
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
\shape slanted
\emph default

\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset


\shape default
\emph on
Typeset with \SpecialChar 
, http://www.lyx.org.
 Text: Bitstream Charter, 9.8/14.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset VSpace vfill
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\noindent
\align center

\size footnotesize
\begin_inset Tabular
<lyxtabular version="3" rows="1" columns="1">
<features>
<column alignment="center" valignment="top" width="90text%">
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\size footnotesize
\emph on
See Goa,1556's catalogue at: http://goa1556.in
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
</lyxtabular>

\end_inset


\shape slanted
\size small

\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset


\begin_inset ERT
status collapsed
\begin_layout Plain Layout

\backslash
rule[[0.5ex]]{1.0\backslash
linewidth}{1pt}
\end_layout
\end_inset


\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Newpage pagebreak
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
thispagestyle{empty}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
sloppy
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
tableofcontents*
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset VSpace vfill
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Chapter*

\series medium
PROLOGUE: Building up to the big day
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\noindent

\lang british
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
markboth{Playing It By Ear| Cheryl Rao}{PROLOGUE: Building up to the big
 day}
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\paragraph_spacing single
\noindent

\lang british
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{PROLOGUE: Building up to the big day}
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\noindent
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
lettrine{D } {oreen}
\end_layout

\end_inset

 sat quietly in the corner of the cement bench of the 
\emph on
balcao
\emph default
 of 
\emph on
The Croft
\emph default
.
 She knew she couldn't be seen from inside the house, even if Mai or Papa
 looked out of the windows on either side of the front door.
 She had drawn herself up into as small a bundle as possible, her bare feet
 on the bench, her arms wrapped around her knees and her head resting on
 her arms.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard

\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\align center

\series bold
The End
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```